# Data validation attributes and the custom resource manager

Tags: c#, validation, attributes

I found the following question/answer in my search for more information on data validation attributes and the `ErrorMessageResourceName` and `ErrorMessageResourceType`:

[How to use DataAnnotations ErrorMessageResourceName with custom Resource Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347650/how-to-use-dataannotations-errormessageresourcename-with-custom-resource-solutio)

Unfortunately it does not have the information I need.  In the answer, a presumed class of `CustomResourceManager` is mentioned:

```
[Required(
    ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(CustomResourceManager), 
    ErrorMessageResourceName = "ResourceKey")]
public string Username { get; set; }
```

But I cannot find the documentation on what this class would look like, what interface it implements, etc.  I need to provide custom error messages for validation failures, but I cannot find the documentation I need to do so.

Comment: Old and such, but here is how it was done in the [ValidationAttribute](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/ValidationAttribute.cs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem today, as I tried to make globalization happen for a wpf app with entity framework and validation attributes.

I tried different solutions and, for now, I ended up creating that `CustomResourceManager` based on the sample that Dave Sexton describes in this post: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/load-resources-string-table-database-t2892227.html

Basically I have implemented my `DatabaseResourceManager` and `DatabaseResourceSet` derived from `ResourceManager` and `ResourceSet` respectively like so:

The `DatabaseResourceManager` Implementation:

```cs
public class DatabaseResourceManager : ResourceManager
{
    #region Singleton pattern http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx
    private static volatile DatabaseResourceManager instance;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();

    private DatabaseResourceManager() : base() { }

    public static DatabaseResourceManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                        instance = new DatabaseResourceManager();
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    protected override ResourceSet InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, bool createIfNotExists, bool tryParents)
    {
        if (culture == null)
            culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        return new DatabaseResourceSet(culture);
    }
}
```

And the `DatabaseResourceSet` implementation:

```cs
public class DatabaseResourceSet : ResourceSet
{
    private readonly CultureInfo culture;
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Hashtable> cachedResources = new Dictionary<string, Hashtable>();

    public DatabaseResourceSet(CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (culture == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("culture");

        this.culture = culture;

        ReadResources();
    }

    protected override void ReadResources()
    {
        if (cachedResources.ContainsKey(culture.Name))
        // retrieve cached resource set
        {
            Table = cachedResources[culture.Name];
            return;
        }

        using (MyDatabaseContext db = new MyDatabaseContext())
        {
            var translations = from t in db.Translations
                       where t.CultureIso == culture.Name
                       select t;
            foreach (var translation in translations)
            {
                Table.Add(translation.Chave, translation.Valor);
            }
        }

        cachedResources[culture.Name] = Table;
    }
}
```

Since my DataBaseResourceManager has the singletone pattern implemented I can easily access it and get the data like so:

```cs
public class LocalizedRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public LocalizedRequiredAttribute() : base()
    {
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        string localErrorMessage = DatabaseResourceManager.Instance.GetString(this.ErrorMessageResourceName) ?? ErrorMessage ?? "{0} is required"; //probably DataAnnotationsResources.RequiredAttribute_ValidationError would is a better option
        return string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, localErrorMessage, new object[] { name });
    }
}
```

Now the drawbacks:

Like said in the pcreview post, winforms doesn't accept this `DataBaseResourceManager`, but in my case since I'm using wpf I didn't have this problem (but had another small memory problem because of the duplication of the `ResourceManager` and a `DictionaryResource`) . Don't know if you can inject the resource manager in the winforms, but that goes beyond your question. 
Another drawback, that you already know, is that we must derived all `ValidationAttribute` used so that the `FormatErrorMessage` is used. `StringLengthAttribute`, `RequiredAttribute`, `RegularExpressionAttribute`, and so on. Which is prone to errors and clumsy. Unfortunately, Microsoft didn't gave us much room here.

Hope I helped, probably I'll review this answer in the future to share my findings on this.

Regards