# ASP.NET MVC enable custom validation attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, sitecore, data-annotations

I'm attempting to create my own model validation attributes for an ASP.NET MVC project.  I've followed the advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347650/how-to-use-dataannotations-errormessageresourcename-with-custom-resource-solutio) but cannot see how to get `@Html.EditorFor()` to recognise my custom attributes.  Do I need to register my custom attribute classes in the web.config somewhere?  A comment on this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100300/asp-net-mvc-custom-validation-by-data-annonation#16100455) seems to be asking the same thing.

FYI the reason I'm creating my own attributes is because I want to retrieve the field display names and validation messages from Sitecore and don't really want to go down the route of creating a class with a ton of static methods to represent each text property, which is what I'd have to do if I were to use

```
public class MyModel
{
    [DisplayName("Some Property")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName="SomeProperty_Required", ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(MyResourceClass))]
    public string SomeProperty{ get; set; }
}

public class MyResourceClass
{
    public static string SomeProperty_Required
    {
        get { // extract field from sitecore item  }
    }

    //for each new field validator, I would need to add an additional 
    //property to retrieve the corresponding validation message
}
```

Comment: There's no overload of EditorFor that acepts string like you are doing, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407414(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: Oops, got a bit mixed up there. Those were properties you could pass into the attribute constructors. Edited my question now.

Comment: Sounds like Sitecore tag is not relevant here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered here:

> [How to create custom validation attribute for MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383669/how-to-create-custom-validation-attribute-for-mvc)

In order to get your custom validator attribute to work, you need to register it.  This can be done in Global.asax with the following code:

```
public void Application_Start()
{
    System.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(
        typeof (MyNamespace.RequiredAttribute),
        typeof (System.Web.Mvc.RequiredAttributeAdapter));
}
```

(If you're using [WebActivator](https://github.com/davidebbo/WebActivator) you can put the above code into a startup class in your `App_Start` folder.)

My custom attribute class looks like this:

```
public class RequiredAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute
{
    private string _propertyName;

    public RequiredAttribute([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        _propertyName = propertyName;
    }

    public string PropertyName
    {
        get { return _propertyName; }
    }

    private string GetErrorMessage()
    {
        // Get appropriate error message from Sitecore here.
        // This could be of the form "Please specify the {0} field" 
        // where '{0}' gets replaced with the display name for the model field.
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        //note that the display name for the field is passed to the 'name' argument
        return string.Format(GetErrorMessage(), name);
    }
}
```